# Do How to convert degrees to decimal degrees?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Do How to convert degrees to decimal degrees?

Example 1:
1. I have - 450 - degrees
2. We need get - 90 from 450

Example 2:
1. I have - 540 - degrees
2. We need get - 180 from 540

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not because  $450^{\circ}\neq90^{\circ}$ and $540^{\circ}\neq180^{\circ}$.

But, for example,  $\sin(450^{\circ}+\alpha)=\sin(90^{\circ}+\alpha)=\cos\alpha$ or

$\cos(540^{\circ}+\alpha)=\cos(180^{\circ}+\alpha)=-\cos\alpha.$